# Is there anything I can do to stop NTP DDoS

Tags: 16.04, internet, ntp

Is there anything I can do to stop this DDoS attack (besides getting 1-5 Gb per second  internet line or ordering DDoS protection)?

[image]

Comment: Blocking the port (UDP 123) will certainly help.  Or just kill the ntp daemon at least for a while.  Is there some reason you need to be a time server?  https://blog.cloudflare.com/understanding-and-mitigating-ntp-based-ddos-attacks/

Comment: There's no reason for running ntp server for me. I will kill ntp daemon. P.S. I tried `sudo service ntp stop` and I got this: `Failed to stop ntp.service. Unit ntp.server not loaded.`

Comment: sudo ufw deny ntp

Answer (score 1):

DDoS attacks are very difficult to defend against.  Even very sophisticated computing environments are routinely taken down by them.

Mitigating the effects of a DDoS attack can be done by employing an Intrusion Detection System (IDS).  The details on how to create one can be found at various web sites that deal with Internet security.

In most cases you just have to wait out a DD0S attack or have some sort of a fail over scheme where a mirror machine takes over

In the case of an attack on NTP, you might get some measure of relief by killing the ntp daemon.

```
sudo service ntp stp
```

And also

```
sudo ufw deny ntp
```

However, these steps may provide little relief.  Blocking udp port 123 at your border firewall or router may be slightly more helpful.

Comment: As I understand I must contact my ISP and ask him to block port 123?
NTP server is not running on my machine.

Comment: If your hosted server is under attack it's highly likely that your ISP is well aware of this.  It would also be unusual for a DDoS attack to last for more than a day or two.  Your best plan would be to contact your ISP and ask if they know that a DDoS is going on and if so, what they are doing about it.

Comment: The attack isn't continuous, it starts every 5-10 minutes and runs for about 1-2 minutes (for nearly a week).  DDOS attack on home computer - that's unusual.